# Win2D Drawing via rendering triangles - bad performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, drawing, polygon, win2d

I would like to create drawing with Win2D library. I have already finished it, but I got some performance issues when I want to redraw larger drawing.
Here is a solution I'm using to display drawing:

```
private Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Numerics.Vector2[] trianglePoints = new Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Numerics.Vector2[3];

private void RenderTriangle(List<Triangle> TriangleList)
{
            using (var drawSession = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                CanvasPathBuilder pathBuilder = new CanvasPathBuilder(Win2DCanvas);

                foreach (Triangle triangle in TriangleList)
                {
                    trianglePoints[0] = triangle.vertexA;
                    trianglePoints[1] = triangle.vertexB;
                    trianglePoints[2] = triangle.vertexC;

                    triangleGeometry = CanvasGeometry.CreatePolygon(Win2DCanvas, trianglePoints);

                    pathBuilder.AddGeometry(triangleGeometry);

                }
                drawSession.FillGeometry(CanvasGeometry.CreatePath(pathBuilder), color)
        }
}
```

Main problem is with this line:

```
triangleGeometry = CanvasGeometry.CreatePolygon(Win2DCanvas, trianglePoints);
```

Creating of about 100 000 of polygons takes about 6000 ms, which is incredible long time.

Do you know faster way to render large number of triangles in Win2D ?

Should I create polygons in C++ and wrap them to C# or something else?

Thank you for replaying.

Comment: Could you keep a list of trianglegeometry variables and only update them if they change?  thus your loop would just be foreach processedtriangle in list addgeometry(processedtriangle)

Comment: This won't work. Problem is with method `CreatePolygon` It takes a very long time.

Comment: but that is my point to avoid calling it unnecessarily...

Comment: But this loop is displaying triangles incrementally and there's no unnecessary triangles.

Comment: Is the color the same for every poly?

Comment: Yes, every poly has the same color.